# Why clicking Back to the list sends me pack to front page? Using hooks

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm setting a value when you click on `Back to List`. As per logic it should not go back to the 1st page which appears when I load the browser. I specified a value

`<a href="#" onClick={() => setPokemon(pokemon.name)}>`

If I wanted to go back to the list page I should have passed null like this.
`<a href="#" onClick={() => setPokemon(null)}>`

Here is the full code.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function App() {
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   queryClient.clear();
  // }, []);

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState(null);
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <div className="App">
        {pokemon ? (
          <Pokemon pokemon={pokemon} setPokemon={setPokemon} />
        ) : (
          <PokemonList setPokemon={setPokemon} />
        )}
      </div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

function usePokemonList() {
  return useQuery("pokemon", async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=50"
    );
    return data.results;
  });
}

function usePokemon(name) {
  return useQuery(["pokemon", name], async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`
    );
    return data;
  });
}

function Pokemon({ pokemon, setPokemon }) {
  const { isLoading, data } = usePokemon(pokemon);
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#" onClick={() => setPokemon(pokemon.name)}>
        Back to the list
      </a>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>{pokemon}</h1>
          <img src={data.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function PokemonList({ setPokemon }) {
  const { isLoading, data } = usePokemonList();
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data.map((pokemon) => (
            <li key={pokemon.name}>
              <a onClick={() => setPokemon(pokemon.name)} href="#">
                {pokemon.name}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pokemon` variable only holds a string value and is not an object with a name property on it. So in your `Pokemon` component when you pass `pokemon.name` in `setPokemon` function you are essentially passing an `undefined` value because the property `name` doesn't exist on the string.

And based on the conditional rendering you are doing in the `App` component since `undefined` is a falsy value, it renders `PokemonList` component instead of retaining the `Pokemon` component. To retain the `Pokemon` component, use `setPokemon(pokemon)` instead of `setPokemon(pokemon.name)`.

```
function Pokemon({ pokemon, setPokemon }) {
  //pokemon variable is of string type.
  console.log(pokemon) //Prints the selected pokemon
  const { isLoading, data } = usePokemon(pokemon);
  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#" onClick={() => setPokemon(pokemon.name)}> {/* Passing pokemon.name is passing a property value that doesn't exist on the object*/}
        Back to the list
      </a>
```

To avoid going back to the list, set the pokemon to its actual name or a non-falsy value.

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => setPokemon(pokemon)}>
        Back to the list
</a>
```

Comment: I actually want to know the logic behind it. Why is it going back..I don't want to prevent it, just want to know the logic. Why it decides to go back to the list page

Comment: By the way your logic is not preventing anything. It is still going back to the list page.

Comment: I've updated the answer that explains the cause of the issue, kindly check.